# Difference between 0 and 0u

Tags: c#, integer, default-value, unsigned

Text from a textbook:

> The uint type is 32-bit unsigned integer type. Its default value is
>   the number 0u or 0U (the two are equivalent). The 'u' letter indicates
>   that the number is of type uint (otherwise it is understood as int).

Then is there a difference between 0 and 0u? If not, then why is the default value '0u'. What is the advantage of suffixing an integer with 'u'?

Why would I ever have to use, say '5u', instead of just using '5'?

Comment: To show that it is unsigned. Some values are better represented as an absolute, like distances.

Comment: One possible use of '5u' is if you like to use the keyword 'var' a lot. If you write " var j = 5; ", then it would be stored as an int and if you write " var j = 5u; ", then it will be stored as a uint.

Comment: @Carcigenicate "  uint distance = 730480; ". Didn't need to use the suffix 'u' here.

Comment: 1. Hungarian notation (putting a type identifier in the name) is usually frowned up. 2. The idea is, if you know that the number will never require a sign, it's good practice to use a type that shows that rule. That extra bit you gain doubles the number's capacity too for the same amount of space, which can be useful.

Comment: 1. Where did I put a type identifier in the name? 'uint' was meant to be the type identifier, it is not included in the variable name. The variable name is 'distance' 2. The type identifier 'uint' means 'unsigned integer' and automatically gives me an extra bit. I wouldn't have to suffix 'u' for that.

Answer (score 5):

By default, the compiler infers a numeric literal to be either double or integral type.

- If the literal contains a decimal point or the exponential symbol, it is a double.
- Otherwise, the literal's type is the *first type* in *this list* that can fit the literal's value: int,uint,long,ulong.

The suffixes u (or U) and l (or L) are rarely necessary, because the uint, long and ulong types can nearly always be either inferred or implicitly converted from int:

```
long i=5; //implicit lossless conversion from int literal to long
```

Similarly d suffix is also redundant, in that all literals with a decimal point are inferred to be double.

```
double x= 4.0d; //(Here, d is redundant)
```

The f (float) and m (decimal) suffixes are the most useful and should always be applied when specifying float or decimal literals. Without the f suffix following lines would not compile, because 3.5 would be inferred to be type double, which has no implicit conversion to float.

```
float f= 3.5f;
```

Similarly, the following line would not compile without the m (decimal) suffix.

```
decimal d=-1.25m;
```

In conclusion, suffixes instructs compilers to consider integral literal (like 123) to be certain type of number- for example long. Similarly, double literal to be considered other types - for example float, decimal and so on.

Comment: In `long i=5`, is `5` an `int` literal or is it inferred as a `long` literal? If the former, does that mean conversion is performed when it is assigned to `i`?

Comment: @Mark, yes there is implicit (lossless) conversion from int to long.

Answer (score 3):

Their type is different. While an unsuffixed integer literal can be interpreted as either `uint` or `int` depending on the context, the `u` suffix forces it to an unsigned type. For instance, you can't assign `5u` to an `int` variable without a cast because it has a `uint` value.

You would use it when the type of the expression matters. For instance, `var i = 5` makes `i` an `int`, but `var i = 5u` makes `i` a `uint`.

You can also use it to select a `uint` overload when passing a literal as a parameter. For instance:

```
void Foo(int x);
void Foo(uint x);

Foo(5);
Foo(5u);
```

In general, though, you don't need it often.

Comment: Why is the default value of uint '0u', and not '0'?

Comment: Because `0` and `0u` don't have the same type, and `0u` is the `uint` one.